# How can I measure duration between moving average crossovers (PineScript)?

Tags: pine-script

Currently, I'm having trouble with coding this condition for PineScript. I would like to add an entry condition that looks at the duration of the previous trend. How can I measure duration between moving average crossovers? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the ta.barssince() function
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}barssince](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dbarssince)

```
sma1 = ta.sma(close, 14)
sma2 = ta.sma(close, 50)
cond = ta.crossover(sma1, sma2)
since_cond = ta.barssince(cond)
plot(since_cond)
```